# @Input ngOnChanges generates a new nested array with my passed in array - how can I avoid this?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm pretty new to Angular and I'm not quite sure if I'm just doing something wrong with `@Input()` and `ngOnChanges()` in my code or if my whole setup isn't correct.

My setup is as follows:

I have some API generated data. My service gets the data and holds logic to do some filtering.

My parent component holds a `filtercomponent` which has a button "apply filter" (which uses the logic in my service) and a `tablecomponent` to display the data.

The filtering works fine and I do get the desired filtered data but how do I pass JUST this array to the `tableviewcomponent`? If I do it via `@Input()` and run `ngOnChanges` I get a nested array.

How do I solve this?

**Parent TS:**

```js
tabellenDaten: any[];

constructor(private filterservice: BdService) {}

ngOnInit() {}

onDisplayTable(filter: BdFilter) {
  this.filterservice.getBdTabelle(filter).subscribe(
    (daten) => {
      console.log('tabellendatenneu', daten);
      this.tabellenDaten = daten;
    },
    (error) => console.log('error: ', error),
    () => { }
  );
}
```

**Parent HTML which holds a `filtercomponent` and a `tablecomponent`:**

```html
<div class="v-flex-container-filter">
  <app-allfilter-bd
    (emitFilter)="onDisplayTable($event)"></app-allfilter-bd>
</div>

<div class="v-flex-container">
  <app-tabelle
    [tabellenDaten]="tabellenDaten"></app-tabelle>
</div>
```

When I log it I do get the desired table like: `Array(148)[{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]`.

Now, when using `[tabellenDaten]="tabellenDaten"` and using `@Input()`...

**Child TS (table logic):**

```js
@Input() tabellenDaten: any[];

ngOnChanges(...tabellenDaten: any) {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(tabellenDaten);
  console.log('TABELLENDATEN', tabellenDaten);
}
```

...I do get the results of the `ngOnChanges` method (`currentValue`, `firstChange` and `previousValue`) which ALSO holds my data array but how do I get JUST the single array?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `ngOnChanges` is: [`ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges#ngOnChanges)

So your code should be:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: simpleChanges) {
  // if 'tabellenDaten' has changed it will be available as a field on 'changes'.
  if (changes.tabellenDaten) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(changes.tabellenDaten.currentValue);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use RxJS with `async` pipe provided by angular.

Instead of subscribe `this.filterservice.getBdTabelle(filter)`, you can assign the observable :

```
tabellenDaten$: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(private filterservice: BdService) {}

ngOnInit() {}

onDisplayTable(filter: BdFilter) {
  this.tabellenDaten$ = this.filterservice.getBdTabelle(filter);
}
```

Then in your template use `async` pipe :

```
<div class="v-flex-container-filter">
  <app-allfilter-bd
    (emitFilter)="onDisplayTable($event)"></app-allfilter-bd>
</div>

<div class="v-flex-container">
  <app-tabelle
    [tabellenDaten]="tabellenDaten$ | async"></app-tabelle>
</div>
```

And finally you don't need to assign your array to MatTableDataSource but you can pass you array directly to mat-table :

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="tabellenDaten">
```

You should always consider to not subscribe your Observable in your component unless you unsubscribe it manually. Otherwise use `async` and let the pipe subscribe/unsubscribe for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, too! I've seen that approach before, but since I'm really a bloody beginner and like to understand what I'm doing I had a hard time using the other posts for my own code. Nevertheless!!! Your answer is working very well and I'm going with this one!!! But I would like to keep the first answer to be the (first) accepted one since I hope it also helps other beginners to really understand the basics - like it helped me.

Comment: Don't worry I understand ! RxJs is not so simple to use but you should consider to use its features from the beginning.  I saw a lot of issue like memory leak, complexity, etc. because of wrong/poor usage of  `.subscribe()`

Comment: `async` pipe is not so hard to understand. It only subscribe your Observable and return result. Then when your component is destroy, the pipe unsubscribe the Observable avoiding to keep connection open or to manually close it (less technical code)

Comment: :) you're right - it's just a lot of new stuff to consider so I'm happy to find help and different approaches but I surely will look into all issues.